# Understanding authentication in a Java Application Server

Tags: spring-security, jboss7.x, jaas, shiro, seam3

I'm currently working on a project running on JBoss AS 7 that requires authentication from a variety of sources. I'm trying to get an understanding of the various components that combine to provide authentication.

I have some assumptions / guesses as to how this all fits together, but I need to make sure that my understanding is correct. So below is what I understand to be the authentication process for JBoss AS7.

---

You have a security realm that defines how users are authenticated. This realm is then exposed to your application in order to secure some or all of it. In AS7 this is configured in the <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.0"> element.

The realm can be configured to authenticate users against a variety of sources using login-modules, such as a database, LDAP, a local file or something else. Multiple login-modules can be defined, and you can specify some combination of login-modules must "succeed" in order for authentication to occur.

The actual username and passwords are passed in via a mechanism defined in the web.xml file (for servlets), defined in the <login-config> element.

---

Assuming that the above process is correct (and it may not be):

- Does this whole authentication process fall under a specification like JAAS, or is JAAS just a small or optional part of this procedure?
- Do all types of <auth-methods>'s (i.e. BASIC, DIGEST and FORM) work with all kinds of login-modules? [This page](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Securing+the+Management+Interfaces#SecuringtheManagementInterfaces-Authentication) would seem to suggest not, but I haven't seen any clear documentation matching <login-module> options <login-config> options.
- The username and password flow from a login-config to a login-module seems straight forward enough, but what happens with systems like OpenID or OAuth where there are intermediary steps (like redirection to external login pages)?
- How do projects like [Seam 3 Security](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/security/latest/reference/en-US/html_single/#security-authentication), [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/) and [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) fit into this picture?

Comment: To follow up on Yves' answer, you can find out more about Apache Shiro here: http://shiro.apache.org Feel free to post to the list if you have any trouble.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

JavaEE security specification leaves a lot of space to container implementors so I will focus on JBoss implementation to answer.

**JBoss security implementation**

JBoss relies on JAAS authentication to implement JavaEE security. That way it takes benefits from a stable API and can use [existing `LoginModule` implementations](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/html/Security_Guide/ch12.html). Login modules are used to authenticate a subject but also to add roles to `Subject`. JAAS provides mechanisms for authorization, permission checking and JBoss uses it internally.

JAAS [LoginModule](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/security/auth/spi/LoginModule.html?is-external=true) does not only supports password-based authentication but also token-based authentication.

**Token based authentications**

A good example of what can be done in JBoss thanks to JAAS is the [HTTP Negotiation support for Kerberos SPNEGO](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossNegotiation): an additional `auth-method` named `SPNEGO` is implemented thanks to a Tomcat Authenticator and token validation uses [JavaSE standard Kerberos LoginModule](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/security/auth/spi/LoginModule.html?is-external=true).

By the way, the LoginModule API is not a requirement, it may even be too complex for some protocols. For instance, the implementation to support [OpenID with PicketLink](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenIDIntegrationWithPicketLink) only uses Servlet API.

**Third party security libraries**

These libraries often provide security layers to an application running a JavaEE or pure Java context, even if it does not take benefits from JavaEE specifications for authentication or role-based authorization.

Spring Security provides other abstractions than JavaEE security for applications developers to implement authentication and authorization, mainly thanks to `ServletFilter` when a web application is concerned. A large panel of choices is available to secure his application: it is possible to mix multiple options like: JAAS usage, JavaEE container security usage or Spring Security specific implementations (the case of OpenID and OAuth). There is no dependency to JavaEE either so it may be use almost in any situation when running on JavaSE. Most architect choose to build application security on Spring Security to have the liberty to switch specific implementations in the future.

Apache Shiro is really similar to Spring Security but it is younger and probably easier to set up.

Seam security does not rely on JavaEE security or JBoss but only on Servlet and JSF APIs. It is obviously the easiest option for JSF/Seam-based web application. Behind the scene, it uses [PicketLink](http://www.jboss.org/picketlink) implementations.

**As a conclusion**, the question to use third party libraries in addition or in replacement to JavaEE security depends on architectural choices: application complexity, vendor independence and portability, control on implementations for bug fixes or improvements. In your specific context, having multiple authentication sources requires a flexible solution like Spring Security which supports [authentication provider chaining](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.x/reference/authentication-common-auth-services.html) (or Shiro).